# How to understand rwx permissions for directories?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, chmod

What does it mean to read, write, and execute a directory? It's intuitive on files, but I don't understand it for directories.

Answer (score 12):

If you have **write permission** for a directory, you can create new entries (files/folders/etc).

If you have **read permission** for a directory, you may list `ls` the directories contents.

If you have **execute permission** for a directory, you may change `chdir` into that directory.

For more information, please see this thread: http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/98744-about-read-write-execute-permissons-directory.html

Answer (score 4):

A read in a directory implies you can do a `ls` in it -- thus reading what's in that directory.

A write enables you to write a file in the directory. This one is fairly intuitive.

An execute is a little bit less intuitive. An execute allows you to `cd` into a directory.

You could do a read in a directory without actually being in it. A possible use for execute only permissions on a directory would be if you want someone to be able to `cd` in a directory but you don't want him to be able to see what files/folders are in that directory (implying that the user knows the file/folder name to access within that directory)

Comment: To expand on the "write" permissions - this allows you to create, rename, and delete files, but some of the metadata on files (permissions, dates, etc.) may still be read-only, because they are stored in the inode (or similar structure) and not in the directory. The exact details depend on what file system is in use, though...

Comment: When I try as a non-root user to create a file or write into a file whose parent directory is owned by root with permissions drwxrwxrwx, I get an error ("read only file system"). Any idea why? I can't find this in the documentation.