# What is the reason that kernel need execution permission to traverse in directories?

Tags: unix, memory-management, filesystems, directory-structure

In *nix it is being said that, everything is considered as file (even it is a directory). Then, If directory is a file which does not contain any binary or any executable data, but only contain inode number and file name, then what is the need of "execute" permission for directory file ???

[Here i attached screen-shot, that showing directory has execute permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlkc.png)

also i have seen(on another site) directory's Execute permission means:
"Execute bit = You can make this directory your working directory".

but just making "directory as our working directory" is it the only one reason to provide "Execute" permission for directory ??

please can any one provide the exact reason for "execute" permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand rwx permissions for directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867628/how-to-understand-rwx-permissions-for-directories)

Comment: @andrew Henle: ya there may some duplications, I have read there answers too, but I want to know, how it is exactly happen, what are the operations could not be perform by the kernel when  directory has no execute permission
Or What happens in the interior, that requires execute permission to kernel.